# How do I get an Expression Blend Keyspline control?

Tags: c#, .net, controls

I need a control in my C# program that behaves exactly the same as MS Expression Blend keyspline control - is there any way to get hold of that control and add it to my application?

As a side note it'd be nice to use some of the other controls that appear in that applications as well

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by add it to your application? If you're developing a C# WPF application you can already add it using the Blend designer or programatically in Visual Studio.

You can inherit from all the WPF controls to create new ones that enhance the behaviour if needed. If you simply want to customise the feel of a control you can use styles within Expression Blend. If you want to customise the complete look, feel and behaviour of a control you also have the option of templates.

Answer (score 0):

Ok sorry for uing the wrong terminology.

I want to add the control into Visual Studio 2005's toolbox (or indeed Expression Blend's Asset Library) so that I can drag and drop it into any C# WPF applications I create.

The problem is I don't know what the Expression Blend Keyspline control is called and how to get access to it (ie what dll to include as a reference)?

I can try and go through Expression Blend's dll's etc searching for the control but I'm not sure A) that this will work, B) that its a bit long winded, C) what the licensing is for such controls.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is add a Storyboard, that's where you will then have the option to set the animations including KeySplines for your different controls. A KeySpline by itself is not actually a control it is an animation that acts on a control.

To add a Storyboard click the little plus icon at the top of the "Objects and Timeline" panel (to the right of where is says No Storyboard Open).